# How can I mock/fake/stub sealed OracleException with no public constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, mocking, oracleclient

In my tests I need to test what happens when an OracleException is thrown (due to a stored procedure failure).  I am trying to setup Rhino Mocks to

```
Expect.Call(....).Throw(new OracleException());
```

For whatever reason however, OracleException seems to be sealed with no public constructor.  What can I do to test this?

**Edit:** Here is exactly what I'm trying to instantiate:

```
public sealed class OracleException : DbException {
  private OracleException(string message, int code) { ...}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Oracle changed their constructors in later versions, therefore the solution above will not work.

If you only want to set the error code, the following will do the trick for 2.111.7.20:

```
ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(OracleException)
            .GetConstructor(
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, 
                null, 
                new Type[] { typeof(int) }, 
                null
                );

Exception ex = (OracleException)ci.Invoke(new object[] { 3113 });
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is how you do it:

```
    ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(OracleException).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] {typeof(string), typeof(int)}, null);
    var c = (OracleException)ci.Invoke(new object[] { "some message", 123 });
```

Thanks to all that helped, you have been upvoted

Answer (score 9):

For oracle's managed data access (v 4.121.1.0) the constructor changed again

```
var ci = typeof(OracleException).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) }, null);
var c = (OracleException)ci.Invoke(new object[] { 1234, "", "", "" });
```

Comment: How do i do it for ddtek 4.2.0.0 ? I am new to refleciton and i Can't identify any constructors

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the Oracle.DataAccess.Client data provider client. I am having trouble constructing a new instance of an OracleException object, but it keeps telling me that there are no public constructors. I tried all of the ideas shown above and keep getting a null reference exception.

```
object[] args = { 1, "Test Message" };
ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(OracleException).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic 
     | BindingFlags.Instance, null, System.Type.GetTypeArray(args), null);
var e = (OracleException)ci.Invoke(args);
```

When debugging the test code, I always get a NULL value for 'ci'.

Has Oracle changed the library to not allow this? What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do to instantiate an OracleException object to use with NMock?

By the way, I'm using the Client library for version 10g.

Thanks,

Charlie

Answer (score 3):

Use reflection to instantiate the OracleException object? Replace

```
new OracleException()
```

with

```
object[] args = ... ;
(OracleException)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(OracleException), args)
```

Comment: This seems like it will work, how do I specify constructor arguments?

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(OracleException), new object[] {yourParams});

Answer (score 3):

Use reflection to instantiate OracleException. See [this blog post](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.canerten.com/reflection-with-private-members/&hl=en&strip=1)

Answer (score 3):

You can always get all the constructors like this

```
ConstructorInfo[] all = typeof(OracleException).GetConstructors(
  BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);`
```

For `Oracle.DataAccess` 4.112.3.0 this returned 7 constructors

[image]

The one I wanted was the second one in the list which took 5 arguments, `int, string, string, string, int`. I was surprised by the fifth argument because in ILSpy it looked like this

```
internal OracleException(int errCode, string dataSrc, string procedure, string errMsg)
{
    this.m_errors = new OracleErrorCollection();
    this.m_errors.Add(new OracleError(errCode, dataSrc, procedure, errMsg));
}
```

So, to get the constructor I wanted I ended up using

```
ConstructorInfo constructorInfo =
  typeof(OracleException).GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(int) },
    null);`
```

Answer (score 2):

Good solution George. This also works for SqlException too:

```
        ConstructorInfo ci = typeof( SqlErrorCollection ).GetConstructor( BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] {  }, null );
        SqlErrorCollection errorCollection = (SqlErrorCollection) ci.Invoke(new object[]{});

        ci = typeof( SqlException ).GetConstructor( BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof( string ), typeof( SqlErrorCollection ) }, null );
        return (SqlException) ci.Invoke( new object[] { "some message", errorCollection } );
```

-dave

Answer (score -1):

Can you write a trivial stored procedure that fails/errors each time, then use that to test?

Comment: I don't want to have to hit the database every time!