# How to raise an OracleException for test purposes

Tags: c#, oracle, exception, oracleexception

I have a function that executes some SQL commands, and I've created a logger that I write in the file the command that was executed and the number of rows that were affected, but I also need to write down the command that may have raised an OracleException, so I've done this piece of code:

```
public string ExecuteCommand(List<string> comandos)
        {
            var excepção = string.Empty;
            var executar = new OracleCommand
            {

                Connection = Updater.OraConnection,
                CommandType = CommandType.Text
            };

            try
            {
                Logg("Inicio da execução de comandos");
                foreach (var variable in comandos)
                {
                    excepção = variable;
                    executar.CommandText = variable;
                    throw new OracleException(0, "comando", "stuff", "adasds");
                  var Afectados =  executar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Logg(variable);
                    Logg("Linhas afectadas: " + Afectados);

                }

            }
            catch (OracleException)
            {
                Logg("Erros:");
                Logg(excepção);
                return excepção;

            }

            return excepção;


        }
```

I've tried to search everywhere but I cant fint any suitable or even focused answers, so Im kinda lost for why cant I raise an oracleException as I did like this: `throw new OracleException(0, "comando", "stuff", "adasds");`

> It just says that Cannot access constructor here due to its protection level.
>   Any help would be aprecciated

Comment: The constructor of the "OracleException"-Class is private. So you can't simply create an object of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I mock/fake/stub sealed OracleException with no public constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122215/how-can-i-mock-fake-stub-sealed-oracleexception-with-no-public-constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class OracleException : Exception
{

}
```

The class needs to have its scope set to public or internal. The constructor cannot be accessed as its a private class.

Comment: I wonder why I coulnd't find that explanation anywhere, thank you a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to simulate the exception being thrown and do not care about interrogating the object then.

```
private OracleResilienceManager CreateSut()
{
    return new OracleResilienceManager(_resilienceSettings);
}

throw System.Runtime.Serialization.CreateSafeUninitializedProtectedType<OracleException>();
```

In my case I was testing a retry policy and wanted to test the retry logic when this exception is thrown. Had no need to access the object itself.